# Creating a copy of an previous event

Tags: civievent

I am copying a previous event but the registration page shows the old date and address. I have updated the event in Event Location, but it will not change. How can i change this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

how are you copying/duplicating the old event?

if you have an event that you do often, it's best to make an event template and then you can create new events based on the template and edit the details that change (like date) but the ones that don't get populated automatically

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misreading your question, but the date of the event is updated on the first tab, "Info and Settings" towards the bottom (rather than the "Event Location" tab.)